# Aws workspace can't access website hosted in aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ec2

I have a website hosted in an ec2 instance. It works ok from outside, for example from my home network.

However, i can't access this website from my aws workspace. Both ec2 instance and workspace's directory use security group with 0.0.0.0 rule in inbound and outbound rules.

Comment: Please edit your question to show an nslookup and a ping, as well as ideally a network topology diagram showing VPC, subnets, and where EC2 / Workspace is located. My first guess is it has something to do with private IP or routing. We can't really help with the information you've provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my proxy to google (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) then it works. So no problem with the inbound and outbound rules.